# Reading intended recipient from Undeliverable emails via Interop for Outlook

Tags: interop, outlook

I've created an application, which is used to loop through the emails in an inbox and find all the undeliverable, mailbox full or delayed emails and generate a report.

The usual routine is to loop through all the emails in the inbox (up to a specified date).

If an email is undeliverable use regex to find the email. This works 95% of the time as this information is contained in the body of the Undelivered message (ReportItem).

So, my problem is I have a few emails which are returning blank emails to the report making it nigh on impossible to clean them or easily report that we have a problem with someone's email.

I have found that the information in the Internet Headers has who the mail was intended for, but cannot find anything on if it is possible to use an interop or some other object to obtain this information.

If anyone else has come across this problem and knows of a work around I would be very grateful.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like what I want isnt part of the ReportItem properties.

The possible options are Extended IMAPI, CDO or Redemption

http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Outlook/microsoft.public.outlook.program_vba/2004-11/0084.html

Answer (score 3):

I was looking to automate an outlook mail box to move all undelivered emails and store the email address of the recipient of the undeliverable message in a list, so that I can later check if an entry of the list is present in an excel column and then remove it from the excel. I hope this helps !
I've found a Python solution for this problem. A python library that is used to connect to the outlook is win32com, so first we import all libraries that we will need:

```
import win32com.client
import re
import datetime as dt
from tqdm import tqdm
import time
import extract_msg
```

This is a good way to connect to a specific outlook account, if you have :

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
accounts= win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").Session.Accounts
```

Then create a loop that iterates through the whole outlook and gets to the specified mail account:

```
for account in accounts:
    inbox = outlook.Folders(account.DeliveryStore.DisplayName)
    if account.DeliveryStore.DisplayName == 'place_your_account_name_here':
            for folder in inbox.Folders:
```

Find the folder in outlook you wish to check by folder name, 
so if you would want to iterate through Inbox, type "Inbox" instead of "Folder_name"

```
if folder.__str__() == "Folder_name":
    messages = folder.Items                                
    messages.Sort('[ReceivedTime]', True)
    if folder.Folders.Item('Undeliverable'):
        undeliverable = folder.Folders.Item('Undeliverable')

    list_of_undelivered_email_addresses = my_super_function(messages,undeliverable)
```

After we have reached the mail items and declared the undeliverable subfolder as "undeliverable", we specify the time period for which we want to do the below function:

```
def my_super_function(messages,undeliverable):

    list_of_undelivered_email_addresses = []

    last_n_days = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days = 25)

    messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" +last_n_days.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')+"'")

    rl= list()
```

I have found that the msot popular times of undeliverable email addresses present some sort of an error, and below the error is the original version of the email I have sent. Most of them (with very few exceptions, have a line that says:
To: "Some_email_address" ....
This is why I used this regular expression to get read the whole line after my pattern (which is "To: "")

```
    pattern = re.compile('To: ".*\n?',re.MULTILINE)

    for counter, message in enumerate(messages):
```

It is very important that you save the email somewhere on your PC, because otherwise as soon as you read it's body, the email gets encrypted.

```
 message.SaveAs("undeliverable_emails.msg")
            f = r'specify_the_absolute_path_where_you_want_it_saved'  
            try:
                    msg = extract_msg.Message(f)
                    print(counter)
```

Search the saved msg body for the keyword Undeliverable:

```
                    if msg.body.find("undeliverable")!= -1 or msg.body.find("Undeliverable")!= -1 or msg.subject.find("Undeliverable")!= -1 or msg.subject.find("undeliverable")!= -1 or msg.body.find("wasn't found at")!= -1:
```

Save the actual email to a list, so you can move it to the undeliverables subfolder later

```
rl.append(message)


                            m = re.search(pattern, msg.body)
                            m = m[0]

                            mail_final = m.split('"')[1]   

                            list_of_undelivered_email_addresses.append(mail_final)
                            list_of_undelivered_email_addresses=list(filter(None, list_of_undelivered_email_addresses))


                    else:
                            print('this email is not an undeliverable one')
            except:
                    pass
```

Move all mails in the list to the undeliverables folder:

```
if len(rl) ==0:
            pass
    else:
            for m in tqdm(rl):
                    m.Move(undeliverable)

    return list_of_undelivered_email_addresses
```

Here is the full code:

```
import win32com.client
import re
import datetime as dt
from tqdm import tqdm #tqdm gives you the progress bar
import time
import extract_msg

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
accounts= win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").Session.Accounts

def my_super_function(messages,undeliverable):    
        list_of_undelivered_email_addresses = []
        last_n_days = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days = 25)
        messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" +last_n_days.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')+"'")
        rl= list()
        pattern = re.compile('To: ".*\n?',re.MULTILINE)       
        for counter, message in enumerate(messages):
                message.SaveAs("undeliverable_emails.msg")
                f = r'some_absolute_path'  
                try:
                        msg = extract_msg.Message(f)
                        print(counter)
                        if msg.body.find("undeliverable")!= -1 or msg.body.find("Undeliverable")!= -1 or msg.subject.find("Undeliverable")!= -1 or msg.subject.find("undeliverable")!= -1 or msg.body.find("wasn't found at")!= -1:
                                rl.append(message)
                                m = re.search(pattern, msg.body)
                                m = m[0]
                                mail_final = m.split('"')[1]   
                                list_of_undelivered_email_addresses.append(mail_final)
                                list_of_undelivered_email_addresses=list(filter(None, list_of_undelivered_email_addresses))
                        else:
                                print('else')
                except:
                        pass
        if len(rl) ==0:
                pass
        else:
                for m in tqdm(rl):
                        m.Move(undeliverable)
        return list_of_undelivered_email_addresses

for account in accounts:
        inbox = outlook.Folders(account.DeliveryStore.DisplayName)
        if account.DeliveryStore.DisplayName == 'desired_email_address':
                for folder in inbox.Folders:
                        if folder.__str__() == "Inbox":
                                messages = folder.Items                               
                                messages.Sort('[ReceivedTime]', True)
                                if folder.Folders.Item('Undeliverable'):
                                        undeliverable = folder.Folders.Item('Undeliverable')                                      
                                list_of_undelivered_email_addresses = my_super_function(messages,undeliverable)
```

Answer (score 1):

An old post, but FYI, you don't have to use regex to get undelivered emails, you can get all undelivered/bounce back calls by checking the value in

```
message.Class
```

It returns a number, 46 means that this is a bounced email. 43 is the normal received email.

The complete list of numbers that related to message.Class are in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.olobjectclass?view=outlook-pia

Comment: think this might have come 7 years after :) glad to see there is something.